# Objective-C, How to rotate images and stretch for PDF printing

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf-generation

I am trying to get an app that prints four photos onto a pdf. These photos could be any size and any orientation.

I am trying to get these photos printed into specific places in the pdf. If the image is portrait i simply want it printed, if it is landscape i obviously want to rotate it before i print it. I also want the photo to fill the entire of the space.

I have been trying for a while and this is closet i have got.

[image]

As you can see the bottom two photos (landscape so have been rotated) are narrower than the portrait ones at the top. Can anyone see issues with the code below. I apologise, it is attempt after attempt so might not be 100% clear.

Acutal calls

```
[PDFCreator DrawPhoto:Image1 : CGRectMake(60, 60, 226, 340)];
[PDFCreator DrawPhoto:Image2 : CGRectMake(326, 60, 226, 340)];
[PDFCreator DrawPhoto:Image3 : CGRectMake(60, 407, 226, 340)];
[PDFCreator DrawPhoto:Image4 : CGRectMake(326, 407, 226, 340)];
```

Code

```
+ (void) DrawPhoto : (UIImage*) Photo : (CGRect) Location{
    [[PDFCreator imageWithImage:[PDFCreator scaleAndRotateImage:Photo]     scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(Location.size.width, Location.size.height) ] drawInRect:Location];
}

+ (UIImage*) scaleAndRotateImage: (UIImage*) imageIn
{
    if(imageIn.size.width > imageIn.size.height)
    {
        CGFloat rads = M_PI * 90 / 180;
        float newSide = MAX([imageIn size].width, [imageIn size].height);
        CGSize size =  CGSizeMake(newSide, newSide);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, newSide/2, newSide/2);
        CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, rads);
        CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),CGRectMake(-[imageIn size].width/2,-[imageIn size].height/2,size.width, size.height),imageIn.CGImage);
        imageIn = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();   
    }
    return imageIn;
}

+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Thanks